# Local network shared drive with caching

Tags: windows, networking, nas, cache, shared-folders

I would like to set-up a shared network drive across a local network, with offline avalability (caching).

Basic folder syncing is not working in this case, because it does not ensure synchronization. When a file has been modified on the server, if the client version is not yet or being updated, the local program file reads should be guaranteed to get up to date files, if it is connected to the server.

Client machines are using windows 7 professional.

It seems that windows file sharing with "offline" mode does the job, but is there any alternative that could use a small system such as a NAS or a linux embedded system as the server?